# How to generate Oauth2 client id and secret using python script only by using gmail id and password?

Tags: python, oauth-2.0

I want to generate Oauth2 client-id and secret (web type) only from python script. I do not want use any browser or manual steps to be done. only gmail id and password will be provided to that script.project name doesn't matter, it can be anything (in https://console.developers.google.com/). I need this badly for a project. Advanced Thanks for any kind of help.

Comment: Oauth2 is not only about login with username/password, but also about requesting rights for a specific application. I don't think there is a way to work arround this

Comment: I am not asking about any formal way, like I tried to capture all http traffic that is being sent from my pc to server, during the process of generating client secret. later I tried using another tool (not browser) to send only these traffics. It was almost working... what I cudnt do is that extract information from their java script encoded or rendered webpage . I used python module "selenium" and "pyqt4" (webkit), but nothing seems to work... so I would appreciate any informal way (what I can turn into python script) also...

Comment: Oauth2 is just designed to prevent such attacks...

Comment: Yeah , it seems so. :) whatever thanx for your time